# Prove that 2-Colourability is in L from Undir-Reachability is in L

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, space-complexity, colorings

Let Undir-Reachability be the following problem:
given an undirected graph G and two specified vertices s and t in G, is there a path from s to t in G?

I need to prove that the 2-Colourability is in L, by knowing that Undir-Reachability belongs to the complexity class L.

I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: a graph is not bipartite if there is a walk of odd length from a vertex to itself.